# Display Gantt Chart in MVC3 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, gantt-chart

In my project, I have created a html label with certain attributes which include the project start date and the project end date.

I am supposed to add all the month columns where I want to show the months highlighted from start date month to end date month.

I do not want any kind of functioning in there.

Just highlight the months from start to end.

I thought its supposed to be a gantt chart.

But in the net, all I can find is the gantt chart schedulers and not just the display.

Is there a way to do it?

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is you're goal to display just the month names or display the months with all the dates inside and highlight all days from the start day to the end day?

Comment: I just display the months and highlight the months from start month to end month in each row.

Comment: That's pretty easy, let me right you an answer... one moment...

Comment: Okay, I added it.  Let me know if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Would this do the trick?

http://taitems.github.io/jQuery.Gantt/

Gantt chart for jquery, would work with MVC3 rather well.

Comment: Thanks.. i will check this out is this can be of any help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your goal is to "display just the month names and highlight all months from the start month to the end month," try the following:

**Model:**

```
public class Month
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool isHighlighted { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult MyCalendar()
{
    // code untested; not sure of the exact syntax since I don't have VS on this machine...

    DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1 - DateTime.Now.Day);  // Make sure we start on the first that month
    DateTime endDate = currentDate.AddMonths(11);

    DateTime highlightStartDate = currentDate.AddMonths(3);
    DateTime highlightEndDate = currentDate.AddMonths(9);

    List<Month> months = new List<Month>();

    while (currentDate <= endDate)
    {
        if (currentDate >= highlightStartDate && currentDate <= highlightEndDate)
        {
           months.Add(new Month({
                         Name = currentDate.ToString("MMMM"),
                         isHighlighted = true
                     });
        }
        else
        {
            months.Add(new Month({
                          Name = currentDate.ToString("MMMM"),
                          isHighlighted = false
                      });
        }
        currentDate = currentDate.AddMonths(1);
    }

    return View(months);
}
```

**View:**

```
@model List<MyMvcProject.Models.Month>

<style>
    .month { display: inline-block; float: left; }
    .highlighted { background-color: green; }
</style>

@foreach(Month month in Model)
{
   <div class="month
        @if (month.isHighlighted)
        {
            @:highlighted
        }
   ">@month.Name</div>
}
```

Comment: Hello...Thank you v much! I think this will work! But i was wondering how to i add these in my razor table and where do i specify the start and end dates for each row. Sorry for asking the particulars cuz i am a beginner!

Comment: @SaraCh no prob, we were all beginners once.  See the code I added for View.